# will DBT support temp table creation like create table #temp1 as select * from tab1 or it works only CTE way

Tags: dbt

I found out a way to handle the temp tables in DBT, write all those in pre-hook and call the final temp table in the outside of the pre-hook, tested and is working fine, able to reduce the code running time from more than 20 mins to 1 min. But I see one problem that we can't see the lineage graph in the DBT documents.
Is there any way to handle the temp tables other than pre-hook and with lineage in Docs?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please review the resource at the end of this comment and expand on your question with a reproducible example as much as possible! Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 14):

You're right in thinking that dbt does not support temporary tables. That's because temporary tables only persist in a single session, and dbt opens one connection/session per thread. Therefore any temporary tables created on one thread would not be visible to a model running on a different thread.

It sounds like CTEs are a performance drag for you though — out of interest, which warehouse are you using?

You've identified two workarounds, and there's another one worth discussing:

**Option 1: Materialize your model as CTEs using the `ephemeral` materialization ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/materializations/#ephemeral))**

*Pros:*

- The models show up in the lineage graph
- You can re-use these transformations in multiple downstream models by `ref`-ing them
- You can test and document these models

*Cons:*

- At some point there is a performance degradation with too many stacked CTEs (especially on older versions of postgres, where CTEs are an optimization fence)
- Compiled SQL can be harder to debug

**Option 2: Use pre-hooks to create temp tables**

I would generally recommend against this — you can't test or document your models, and they won't be in the lineage graph (as you've noted).

**Option 3: Materialize these models as tables in a separate schema, and drop the schema at the end of a run**

I think Michael's suggestion is a good one! I'd tweak it just a little bit:

1. Use the [schema](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/schema/) config to materialize a model in a separate schema

```
{{ config(
  materialized='table',
  schema='my_temporary_schema'
) }}
```

2. Then, at the end of a run, use an `on-run-end` hook ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/on-run-start-on-run-end/)) to drop that schema — in your `dbt_project.yml`:

```
on-run-end: "drop schema my_temporary_schema cascade"
```

*Pros:*

- All the benefits of Option 1
- Sounds like it might be more performant than using CTEs

*Cons:*

- Make sure you don't have any dependent views on top of that schema! They might get dropped when you run a `drop cascade` command! This introduces fragility into your project!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you could get the same result while preserving lineage in the documentation:

1. Write each temp table as a separate model where the logic happens in the pre_hook (like you suggested) and the model is just a view with the logic `select * from YOUR_TEMP_TABLE_NAME`.
2. Instead of using temp tables, create each table as a regular model, and just drop them in the post_hook of the "final" model that uses them or in the `on-run-end` of your `dbt_project.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. creates a source (SRC) model so that you can separate the source from the staging models.
2. Build the source using a staging model directly.

These should both show up on the lineage graphs.